# Can not Waterlock installation

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterlock

For API keys i want to use JWT using waterlock. But i can not install waterlock. the error message is showing bellow.

```
 npm WARN locking Error: EACCES, open '/home/developer/.npm/_locks/waterlock-96592128476e35c7.lock'
npm WARN locking     at Error (native) 
npm WARN locking  /home/developer/.npm/_locks/waterlock-96592128476e35c7.lock failed { [Error: EACCES, open '/home/developer/.npm/_locks/waterlock-96592128476e35c7.lock']
npm WARN locking   errno: -13,
npm WARN locking   code: 'EACCES',
npm WARN locking   path: '/home/developer/.npm/_locks/waterlock-96592128476e35c7.lock' }
npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-34-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "waterlock"
npm ERR! node v0.12.1
npm ERR! npm  v2.5.1

npm ERR! Attempt to unlock /home/developer/Desktop/Sails/AuthTest/node_modules/waterlock, which hasn't been locked
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/developer/Desktop/Sails/AuthTest/npm-debug.log
```

Comment: Do you have write rights to `/home/developer/.npm`?

Comment: I am a new ubuntu user. i have installed npm watching the official documentation. i am not sure about that.

Comment: `sudo chown -R $(whoami) $HOME/.npm` will set you as owner of your npm modules folder. Try that and then retry `npm install waterlock`.

Comment: @DanD. done; user2040589 please consider upvoting and marking my question as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually when you get `EACCES` errors a good start is to see whether you have write rights to the folder where `npm` is writing (you get that in your error, in this case it is `/home/developer/.npm`).

You can see if you have write rights by running

```
ls -l /home/developer/.npm
```

if you see something like

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 SOMEONE-ELSE SOMETHING-ELSE 4.0K Mar 26 16:43 bin
```

rather than

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 developer developer 4.0K Mar 26 16:43 bin
```

it means your user does not own that directory, so you might want to run

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) $HOME/.npm
```

to get those rights.